# How to route avoiding a cerntain zone in OSRM

Tags: maps, osrm

I want to find routes using OSRM (Open Source Routing Machine) avoiding a certain area of the city, specified by a polygon, as an option. One approach is to make two profiles: `car` and `car_avoid_no_drive_zone`. The latter profile looks up each way segment and sets the length to infinity if it is inside the *no drive zone*.

But this approach technically duplicates the pre-processing, disk usage and RAM usage. Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

it is possible to block some area via a "traffic update" by setting 0 speed on all OSM segments on the border of the restricted area and doing only CH contraction or MLD customization. This approach will still generate two graphs. More information here https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Traffic

Another way is to use a coming soon "avoid" feature https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/pull/4315 by defining a "restricted area" class in a profile and using a query parameter like `avoid=restricted` at runtime.